# GROUP_CONCAT() error in h2 [42001-214] , [42122-214]

Tags: sql, h2

i keep getting this error GROUP_CONCAT(""""[*],a.montant, a.type_avance,a.date_avance,
a.remark SEPARATOR '
') as Avance [42001-214] ,and after
i removed GROUP_CONCAT to test the code i got the error:
Column ""  not found; SQL statement [42122-214]
here is my code:

```
SELECT i.n_dossier , concat(\"<html>\",i.nom_prenom,\"<br></html>\") 
,concat(\"<html>\",i.vehicule,\"<br></html>\"),i.prime_totale ,"
+ " i.date_effet , i.date_echean ,GROUP_CONCAT(\"<html>\",a.montant,"
+ " a.type_avance,a.date_avance,a.remark SEPARATOR \"<br>\") as Avance ,i.reste ,i.GSM,"
+ "i.observation ,\"</html>\" FROM info_impayee i LEFT JOIN avance a ON i.n_dossier = "
+ " a.n_dossier GROUP by i.n_dossier,i.date_dossier,i.anuller having i.anuller = ' active '
```

Comment: I respectfully suggest you format your code so the levels of parenthesis show themselves clearly. You may be able to see any error more clearly. Writing SQL that directly generates HTML is a **really** unpleasant programming task and you must be precise about making your code easy for you to read. Or you just go crazy. Ask me how I know this sometime.

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT("<html>",a.montant, a.type_avance,a.date_avance,a.remark SEPARATOR "<br>")` is invalid

Comment: @O. Jones the reason why i used that query it's cuz i had so many problems with the format of the data showing in the jtable   :<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must replace

```
GROUP_CONCAT("<html>",a.montant, a.type_avance,a.date_avance,a.remark SEPARATOR "<br>")
```

with

```
GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT("<html>",a.montant, a.type_avance,a.date_avance,a.remark) SEPARATOR "<br>")
```

GROUP_CONCAT needs to have 1 column, as you see in the sample CONCAT will do  that.

I don't why you use single quorted ' active 'and not double

Comment: the error now is SEPARATOR [*]""<br>""  [42001-214], and i fixed single quorted ' active '

Comment: You need to escape the double quotes or use  single quotes also that doesn't look like the old code so add the new as well

Comment: Character string literals in standard SQL can be surrounded only with single quotes, double quotes are used to quote identifiers.

Comment: @EvgenijRyazanov yes, but escaped characters will work, but we now nee to see the ne string, to get bwhat the error actually means

Comment: No, they won't, excluding few DBMS like MySQL not related to this question.